# How do i find out which Fedora version I'm running from the cli (not uname -a)?

Tags: unix, unix-shell

I want to know if the box is Fedora Core 4 or Redhat 9, or CentOS, etc... not if it has Kernel 2.6.x

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On modern systems you should be able to look in /etc/lsb-release

```
mojo-jojo david% cat /etc/lsb-release 
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=9.10
DISTRIB_CODENAME=karmic
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu karmic (development branch)"
```

This should be the LSB mandated way of finding out the distribution across different Linux distributions.

You should not rely on /etc/issue, as it is used for the login message, and someone might change it.

Comment: on centOS 5.3 that file doesn't exist, but the bin directory provides provides lsb_release as a command alternative

Comment: lsb_release is not available on Fedora (21 Workstation) base image

Comment: From the Wikipedia Linux Standard Base page:  "The command lsb_release -a is available in many systems to get the LSB version details, or can be made available by installing an appropriate package, for example the redhat-lsb package on Red-Hat-flavored Linux distributions such as Fedora.[2]"  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_Standard_Base

Comment: lsb-release does not exist on fedora systems. The correct file is called system-release

Comment: sudo dnf install lsb_release  added the command. it wasn't needed as cat /etc/fedora-release gave the essential information: $ cat /etc/fedora-release 
Fedora release 39 (Thirty Nine)

Answer (score 18):

This perhaps?

[dummyuser@d400 ~]$ ls -l /etc/system-release
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 14 2009-06-04 19:05 /etc/system-release -> fedora-release

[dummuser@d400 ~]$ cat /etc/system-release
Fedora release 11 (Leonidas)

Answer (score 4):

Please see:

- [How do I find out what version of Linux is running?](https://serverfault.com/questions/3331/how-do-i-find-out-what-version-of-linux-is-running)
- [How do I find out the distro of a server?](https://serverfault.com/questions/57616/how-do-i-find-out-the-distro-of-a-server)
- [Determining type of Linux machine](https://serverfault.com/questions/55834/determining-type-of-linux-machine)

Answer (score 4):

Even better, and *nixwide:

```
lsb_release -d
```

Answer (score 2):

I had to do

```
cat /etc/fedora-release
```

Answer (score 0):

Ahh answer to my own question..

cat /etc/issue

Comment: this won't be a reliable way of checking for the server version because any sysadmin can modify the contents of that file.  I modify the /etc/issue and /etc/issue.net files to display the company name and legal notice (and explicitly remove the distro name & version info)(